# Detect if the url in an iFrame has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Is there anyway to detect if a user clicks a link inside of an iframe if the iframe is not on the same domain as the parent page?

EDIT: I don't have access to the iframed page. I only own the parent window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Due to the javascript same-origin policy, you cannot access any members of the iframe's DOM if the iframe did not serve from the same domain as the page on which your javascript is running.

Comment: I understand that it isn't possible to actually detect if something is clicked in the frame, but is there a way to detect if the frame loads a new url? Isn't that not part of the DOM? I could be wrong.

Comment: `document.location` and `window.location` are protected properties that are only accessible to scripts executing on the same domain, so no, I don't think this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (window.domain !== top.domain) {
  // they are not the same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var isInSameDomain = (window.location.host == window.parent.location.host);
```