# Detecting new URL in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Here is what I have:

- www.mydomain.com/Pagex.html - In this page I have an iFrame and it's default url(src) is of an outside/different domain then that of the host page (pagex.html).
- The code loaded inside the iFrame is a user input form with a submit.
- When the user hits submit it logs the data and then redirects to the same url as the hosting page www.mydomain.com/Pagex.html but with an added flag (Pagex.html?xxx=1)... So as you can imagine **the parent page is now loading itself inside it's own iFrame**.

What I would like to do...

Using what i suspect would be JavaScript be able to detect the new URL coming into the iFrame and "then" do 2 things:

1. Hide the iFrame
2. Display/show some text on the main host page (not in the same location where the iFrame was)

   - I suspect this will or could use DIV's and that fine... it's the detection of original URL to a changed/different URL of the iFrame I can't get to work.

URL's
 - Host/main page that loads: www.mydomain.com/Pagex.html
 - Hard coded in iFrame URL/SRC in pagex.html: dev.abcdefg.com/testcode.html
 - New url that is sent to the iFrame via redirect: www.mydomain.com/Pagex.html?xxx=1

Thanks for any help on this!
/Shane

#### UPDATE/MORE INFO

So here one place where "maybe" I can get some info from the iFream to the host page...
When the new/redirected URL loads it comes in with a flag ".com/pagex.asp?XXX=1" ... 
So remember it is now loading a page that I have control over pagex.asp (yes old classic asp, not .HTML) and from the same domain as the host, heck it is the host file being loaded.
In the code of the ASP I have it check for the xxx = 1 (request.querystring) and with that I can control what HTML and JS is sent to the iFrame..
Is there a way with this that i can use the already loaded host page to look for some sort of value that gets pushed down the pipe to the iFrame??

I know this is kind of crazy an iFrame loading it's own host file on submit but I only have so much control...

Thanks

Comment: you could do this `<iframe target="" onLoad="alert(this.contentWindow.location);">` to detect when its on the same page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6626838/detect-if-the-url-in-an-iframe-has-changed

Comment: @c69 since the iframe eventually loads the same domain, that doesnt apply here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that your iframe has a different domain than the main page of the document. As a result, the parent page and the iframe page have pretty much no access to each other's content.

The best thing that you can do is utilize the [window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage) API. However, please be aware [that this API is not available in all browsers yet](http://caniuse.com/#feat=x-doc-messaging)

Comment: you imply that _other domain_ actually wants to collaborate with parent window, which might not always be the case.

Comment: will the browser actually allow the parent page to access and view the URI of the second page that is loaded if it's on the same domain? I do know that the iframe's src attribute will not be updated, but am unsure what occurs when the iframe's page gets changed.

Comment: Have a look at my update/more info